# Weakly link static library via -weak_library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker, static-libraries

### Question:

Is it possible to weakly link a static library (Obj-C)?

### Short Details

I do want my custom static framework (**MyFramework.framework**) to weakly link my other custom static library (**libMyLibrary.a**).

The functionality behind **libMyLibrary.a** is optional and can be omitted if there is *NO* **libMyLibrary.a** being linked by any 3rd party application that uses **MyFramework.framework**.

[I am using `-weak_library`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html). My test application complains that static linker is unable to find **MyLibrary**'s symbol `MyClass` within **MyFramework**'s `ABCTracker.o` symbol:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyClass", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MyFramework(ABCTracker.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How to correctly setup weak linking?

### Full Details

#### Setup

- The Xcode project builds a static Mach-O binary and bundles it into a static framework. The result is **MyFramework.framework** bundle.
- Other project builds a static Mach-O binary and the result is a static lib file **libMyLibrary.a** with a header **MyLib.h**
- **libMyLibrary.a** is removed from **MyFramework.framework** target's *Build Phases* > *Link Binary With Libraries* ([as suggested here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html)). Only **MyLib.h** is available to use library's API from the framework's classes
- NO Bitcode is used neither in the framework, nor in the library
- **MyFramework.framework**, **libMyLibrary.a** and custom application are all written in Objective-C
- The **MyLib.h** defines just one Objective-C class `MyClass`
- **MyFramework.framework** uses `MyClass` from its own class `ABCTracker` conditionally checking for symbol availability during runtime, e.g. `NSClassFromString(@"MyClass") == NULL`
- From **MyFramework** target's *Build Settings* I have set `Other Librarian Flags` and `Other Linker Flags` to same value `-weak_library MyLibrary`:

  ```
  OTHER_LDFLAGS = (
      "-weak_library",
      MyLibrary,
  );
  OTHER_LIBTOOLFLAGS = "-weak_library MyLibrary";
  ```

#### Result

- **MyFramework.framework** builds OK
- After the build I have checked the symbols in the resulting binary and the output was emty (no symbols from the static library were built into static framework binary):

  ```
  $ otool -L MyFramework.framework/MyFramework | grep MyClass
  ```
- Despite that, my test application which is not linked with **MyLibrary** whatsoever, builds with `ld` error:

  ```
  Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyClass", referenced from:
        objc-class-ref in MyFramework(ABCTracker.o)
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  ```

What am I doing wrong here?

#### Other Observations

In **MyFramework** target I set `Other Librarian Flags` and `Other Linker Flags` of  to same value:

- `-lMyLibrary`. Result: `otool` shows the library's symbols are built into the framework (expected).
- `-weak-lMyLibrary`. Result is the same as for `lMyLibrary` (is it expected?)

In **my application** target I set `Other Linker Flags` to `-force_load MyLibrary`. Result: the linker error slightly changes:

```
ld: file not found: MyClass
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Have you ever figured out how to do this? I have struggled with the same problem numerous times. I have a workaround which I will post below as an answer, but it is not as clean as getting XCode to actually weak link a static library

Comment: I solved the original issue (which I didn't post here, to maintain simplicity). The issue was symbols duplicates, when both, **MyFramework.framework** and **my application** staticky linked with **libMyLibrary.a**. I thought weakly linking the library would solve symbol duplicates issue. I went other way, though, by redefining symbols during static lib compilation: Set `OTHER_CFLAGS` to `-DMyClass =MyPrefixMyClass`. It requires separate build targets for **MyFramework.framework** and **my application**.

Comment: It sounds like you never quite got around the issue of `-weak-lMyLibrary` resulting in the same (erroneous) inclusion of symbols as `-lMyLibrary` ?

Comment: @Danny correct.

Answer (score 1):

I have also not been successful at getting XCode to properly weak link a static library, although I have the opposite problem from yours - for me `nm` showed all the symbols from the static library, and not with "U" (undefined) symbol type as you see when you weak link a framework.

But a workaround you can use is the following:

1. Create a new Cocoa Touch Framework project called **MyWrapper.framework** and add **libMyLibrary.a** to it
2. Add `-ObjC` to the linker flags to make sure all the symbols get
   loaded (and `-all_load` if you need non Obj-C symbols)
3. Add your library's headers to the framework's **Public Headers** section in **Build Phases**
4. Build this framework (you'll want to set up an aggregate target to build for all architectures but that is a whole separate topic)
5. Open your **MyFramework.framework** project and add **MyWrapper.framework** to it,  weakly linked (i.e. use the toggle to set it to **Optional** or if you prefer remove it from the **Link Binary with Libraries** phase and add it via `-weak_framework` to **Other Linker Flags**)
6. Now build **MyFramework.framework**
7. In your testing app, remove any reference to **libMyLibrary.a**
8. You should be able to run your testing app with no crash and your code should *not* detect the presence of symbols from **libMyLibrary.a**
9. Add **MyWrapper.framework** to your testing app and then you should see the opposite result - symbols from **libMyLibrary.a** will be found and usable.

Comment: Is **MyWrapper.framework** a *static* framework? Your solution sounds promising. I will give it a try.

Comment: Nope it is a dynamic framework - that is what allows is to properly weak link inside **MyFramework.framework**